# Laptop brightness keys are not recognized by X

Tags: x11, keyboard, udev, acpi

When I run `acpi_listen`, keys are recognized, but in a weird way:

```
~$ acpi_listen
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
9DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000
```

Here you can see that volume keys are recognized fine (same for other multimedia keys).
But when I run `xev`, there is no output for brightness keys at all.
And so brightness keys are not recognized by X.

I use Dell XPS 9560, Arch Linux 5.12.2-arch1-1